# Does using .on to bind click benefit from ngTouch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently our project does not have ngTouch but it will at a future time. We are still learning Angular as we go.

I have this simple directive

```
app.directive('myDir', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            iElm.on('click', function($event) {
                // functionality...
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am doing the binding of the click here instead of using `ng-click` because I don't want the html markup to show.

Will this type of binding take advantage of `ng-touch` when we include it? By that I mean if you use `ng-click` with `ng-touch` included then there will be no more 300ms delay after click/tap. So if I don't use `ng-click` and just use `.on` will it still work the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `touchstart` is a different event than `click`. You would need to do:

```
element.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
  /* ... */
});
```

The above would register a handler for both events at the same time. Also keep in mind that because this event handler is triggered outside of an Angular digest cycle, you need to wrap its contents in `$scope.$apply`.

```
app.directive('myDir', function ($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          // functionality...
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

---

### Edit: Re: Angular digest cycle.

When you do things inside of an angular controller or inside of an angular directive, all of that logic is running inside of an angular digest cycle. The digest cycle is basically angular's event loop. As long as angular is the one that launched a logic path then angular is able to ensure that things happen in the right order. When things happen in the digest cycle as expected angular is able to update the UI appropriately and all is well.

This is important to understand when you do things like register an event handler from inside an angular directive or controller. If the event is triggered by something that *isn't* wrapped in angular magic (like most of the native directives that register DOM event handlers for you behind the scenes) then that logic path is happening ***outside*** of an angular digest cycle. The side effect you'll likely see is that even though the code runs and the scope data is modified as expected, the UI will not be updated. The next time that scope variable changes in a digest cycle suddenly you'll see the change that was made.

To fix this you need to manually register the logic you want to perform with angular so it can perform that logic at the appropriate time during a digest cycle, updating the UI as expected.To do this you simply wrap the logic you want to perform inside of `$scope.$apply` which just takes a simple callback. It then manually begins a digest cycle and calls the callback you supplied during that cycle.

If you're curious, this is literally all the `ng-click` directive does:

```
app.directive('ngClick', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs.ngClick, null, true);
      element.on('click', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          fn(scope, { $event: event });
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

It uses the built-in `$parse` utility to parse out the expression you supply to `ng-click` and execute it. It passes in the local `scope` to the expression so you can use variables in scope inside your expression. This is why you can do `ng-click="myFunction(someScopeVar)"`. It also passes in a custom variable called `$event` available only inside that expression. Notice that it's just literally the JQuery wrapped DOM event. Notice also that Angular wraps the DOM event logic in a call to `$scope.$apply` so that it happens in a digest cycle appropriately.

Comment: Is `touch` the actual string to use or is it just an example? I don't fully understand the digest cycle thing you mentioned. My current example works as is but I would imagine if I am using ng-click instead there is some kind of an advantage?

Comment: Yes, "touch" is an event name. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) are the touch events you can handle on the DOM. As for the angular digest cycle, see my edit.

Comment: Ok, makes sense about the digest cycle. For this simple directive I don't I need it to be in the cycle but it is good to know for the future. Last question, if I bind `click touch` is this the same as using `ng-click` with the ng-touch lib included? Or should I stick with `ng-click` in the html markup?

Comment: You only need to wrap it in `$scope.$apply` if you're modifying `$scope` inside the event handler. Take a look at my example `ngClick` directive at the bottom of my answer to see how angular's own native directive works. [It looks like](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngTouch/directive/ngClick.js) the `ngTouch` directive is doing a bit more than what the default `ngClick` handler does but I believe handling those events in your own handler will work just fine.

Comment: I just looked up the event page and `touch` is an interface, if I bind to it, it does not work. Did you mean something else by `touch` ?

Comment: Sorry, looks like [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) is the event you actually want. Take a look at the [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) page for more details on the TouchEvent interface.